# Website crashes during high load when using Amazon Kinesis Client, issue with number of open connections

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

So my website crashes during high load when using the AmazonKinesisFireHoseClient to put records in kinesis.

I get no exceptions logged it just sort of dies and you need to restart the application to get it to work again, sometimes it just starts working by itself after a crash.

I know it has something to do with the number of connections that are open but I have no idea how to fix it.

this is my logger that I instantiate as a singleton

```
public class KinesisFirehoseLogger<T>
{
    private string streamName;

    private AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient client;

    protected ILogger logger;

    public KinesisFirehoseLogger(IKinesisLogConfig config, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.streamName = config.StreamName;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.PartitionKey = config.PartitionKey;
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(config.AccessKey, config.SecretKey);
        this.client = new AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient(credentials, config.Region);
    }

    public async Task<bool> WriteToKinesisAsync(T logObject)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logObject) + "\n")))
        {
            PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest() { DeliveryStreamName = this.streamName, Record = new Record() { Data = ms } };

            // Put record into the DeliveryStream
            return (await client.PutRecordAsync(putRecordRequest)).HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to use the dispose() method of the AmazonKinesisFirehoseClient somewhere ? How do I know when to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `client.PutRecordAsync` opens the connection then it might make sense to put it in a `using` block as well. For example:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logObject) + "\n")))
{
    PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest() { DeliveryStreamName = this.streamName, Record = new Record() { Data = ms } };

    // Put record into the DeliveryStream
    using (PutRecordResponse response = await client.PutRecordAsync(putRecordRequest))
    {
        return response.HttpStatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok;
    }
}
```